# Backbone single view doesn't work after page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript

If I click a link in the list view of my backbone app the single view is rendered as it should. Navigating back and forth in the browser history works as well. But if I reload the page (the single view) in the browser or enter the url to that specific single view manually it doesn't work. The collection doesn't contain any model then. How can I get that specific model needed for rendering the single view in that case? Thank you

main.coffee

```
  class window.MovieSingleView extends Backbone.View
    tagName: 'div'
    className: 'row'

    initialize: ->
      @template = _.template ($ '#movie-single-view-template').html()

    render: ->
      that = @

      @model.deferred.done ->
        ($ that.el).html(that.template that.model.toJSON())

      @

  class window.Router extends Backbone.Router
    routes:
      '': 'index'
      'movies/:id': 'movieSingleView'

    initialize: ->
      @collection = new Movies()
      @collection.fetch
        reset: true

    index: ->
      moviesView = new MoviesView
        # collection: window.movies
        collection: @collection

      ($ '#container')
        .empty()
        .append moviesView.render().el

    movieSingleView: (id) ->
      # movie = window.movies.get id
      # decoratedMovie = new DecoratedMovie movie

      movie = @collection.get id
      decoratedMovie = new DecoratedMovie movie

      movieSingleView = new MovieSingleView
        model: decoratedMovie

      ($ '#container')
        .empty()
        .append movieSingleView.render().el

  $ ->
    window.app = new Router()

    Backbone.history.start
      pushstate: true

    # window.movies.fetch
    #   reset: true
```

index.html

```
<script type="text/template" id="movie-view-template">
  <td><%= _year %></td>
  <td><a href="#/movies/<%= _id %>"><%= _title %></a></td>
  <td><%= _watched %><td>
  <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right remove"></span></td>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your single view is rendering before your collection has finished fetching. So, you need to only render the view after the collection has finished!